# Getting error: "There is no row at position zero"

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to upload an txt file  with and retreive data from the database for the data which is in the text file.I was working fine before but suddenly this error shows up.

This is what there in text file....

```
X341HRK20140331             1000002                        
W177WAK20140405             1000004                        
R969GOJ20140405             1000005                        
W214VLR20140405             1000006
```

When I load the text file it comes up with this error:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(ofd.FileName);

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && line.Trim().Length>0)
{
   //MUST STRIP ANY LEADING BLANK SPACES
   vrm = line.Substring(0, 7).Trim().Replace(" ",""); 
   eventYear = line.Substring(7, 4);
   eventMonth = line.Substring(11, 2);
   eventDay = line.Substring(13, 2);
   dateOfEvent = eventYear + "-" + eventMonth + "-" + eventDay;
                                enquirerReference = line.Substring(29, 6);
                                dateSettledString="";
                                vq_entry = "";

   //lookup-up other data from ICPS

   string stringCommand = "SELECT t_number, t_reference, t_zone_name, t_street_name, t_camera_ticket, t_date_finally_settled,te_event FROM tickets  inner join  ticket_events on tickets.t_number = ticket_events.te_system_ref WHERE t_number=@enquirerReference";
                                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stringCommand, connection);
                                    command.CommandTimeout = 900;
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enquirerReference", enquirerReference);
                                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                                    DataTable tblTemp = new DataTable("DataSet");
                                    adapter.Fill(tblTemp);

      ticketRef = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_reference"].ToString(); -- this is where I receive this error.                     
      site_zoneName = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_zone_name"].ToString();
      site_streetName = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_street_name"].ToString();
      issue_type = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_camera_ticket"].ToString();
      issue_type = issue_type.Replace("-1", "Camera");
      issue_type = issue_type.Replace("0", "Manual");
      dateSettledString = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_date_finally_settled"].ToString().Trim();
      events = tblTemp.Rows[0]["te_event"].ToString();
      excluded = "";

      //Read Ticket Exclusion File and process
      StreamReader readerTEF = File.OpenText(ticket_exclude_file);
      while ((lineTEF = readerTEF.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
              if (lineTEF == ticketRef)
              {
                  excluded=excluded + "Excluded on Ticket Reference";
              }
            }

       //Read ZoneName Exclusion File and process
       //Check on matching zonename and streetname
       StreamReader readerZNE = File.OpenText(zonename_exclude_file);
       while ((lineZNE = readerZNE.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           testSite=lineZNE.Split('#');
           if (testSite[0] == site_zoneName && testSite[1] == site_streetName)
              {
                  excluded = excluded + "Excluded on Zone & Street name";
               }
        }


        //VOID VRM
       if (vrm.Trim().ToUpper() == "VOID")
         {
              excluded = excluded + "Excluded on VRM";
         }


        DateTime dtEvent = DateTime.Parse(dateOfEvent);
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - dtEvent;
        days_past_event = span.Days;

         if (dateSettledString.Length > 5)
         {
            excluded = excluded + "Ticket Has Already Been Settled";
         }
```

Comment: What error?? I can't see one

Comment: There clearly isn't a row that matches the parameter you're passing in `@enquirerReference`.

Comment: Why don't you compare the code with what it was before you changed it?

Comment: By the way - what is the point of using Trim () *and* Replace (x," ", "") on the same line: vrm = line.Substring(0, 7).Trim().Replace(" ","");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a check, your sql statement might not bring the data always

```
if(tblTemp !=null)
{
    if(tblTemp.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        mticketRef = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_reference"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Also recommend you to use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this case

i.e.

`mticketRef = tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_reference"]!=DBNull.Value? tblTemp.Rows[0]["t_reference"].ToString():"";`

Comment: The documentation says that Rows should return null if no rows are returned. Is this an example of the docs being wrong?

Comment: @huMpty: DbNull.Value.ToString() always results in an empty string. So the result in your suggestion would be exactly the same compare to the result of the OP.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: Sorry didn't get you?

Comment: @MartinMulder: Yes, for string it works. In case the OP using for any other type like decimal, long. I can see OP have just put the line where it gets the error but sql statement select more columns possibly with `date` or `datetime`

Comment: @huMpty duMpty http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx

Comment: thanks Humpty dumpty I have added the rest of the code I have used DBNull.value for the rest of columns but i also have datetime columns in it.can you suggest what to do with those..

Comment: @pretyv5: Did you mean [DataTable.Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx)??

Comment: Yes I have added dbnullvalue to the code it came up with this error like  "NullReferenceException was unhandled"     ---here is the error on this line   internalRef = internalRef.Trim().ToUpper();

Comment: If you have time can we move this to discussion.

Comment: how can you move this to disccussion... can you send the link to it.. please

Comment: Seems there is a minimum reputation to start discussion!! Not sure, but have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)

Comment: If i accept it I can achieve 20 points and can we take this discussion then on..as the answer you provided me has given me a thought to improve my coding but gives me some differernt error to resolve

Comment: It should come up automatically will see

Comment: @pretyv5: try flagging question for a moderator attention